# Right way to handle Mongo Socket Timeout

Tags: mongodb, socket-timeout-exception

I have some code that reads all data from mongodb collection by **iterator**. 
When I catch SocketTimeoutException I'm trying to read again – can I use **this** iterator or I need to start with **new** iterator?.
Is it a correct way to handle SocketTimeoutException?

Comment: What language and mongo driver are you using? Please tag the question with that info.

Comment: I'm using java driver. mongodb version is 3.2 (and 3.0 before update)

Comment: Good, now edit and update your question with some code showing how you are doing it.  Also, welcome to SO! [Please read this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.